# iOS : AVFoundation - Preroll mode set during render" and my app hangs

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I am developing MIDI Player by referring to the following Web-Page.

http://twocentstudios.com/2017/02/20/bouncing-midi-to-audio-on-ios/

I don't do any recording, I just want to play the SMF file.
However, when I run setPreload (true), it says "ASSERTION FAILED: Preroll mode set during render" and my app hangs.
I searched for "Preroll mode set during render" but couldn't find any valid information.

Please help someone.

EDIT:

hi, @dspr.
The percussion sounds even if I don't do "AudioUnitSetProperty (kAUMIDISynthProperty_EnablePreload: 1)".
I think this is because the BANK for percussion is automatically assigned to ch.10.
However, in this state, the piano and guitar and others do not sound.
AVAudioUnitMIDI Instrument needs kAUMIDISynthProperty_EnablePreload to analyze which tone is assigned to which track in the SMF file, right?

Which method does AVAudioUnitMIDIInstrument use to preload SMF files?

(1) AudioUnitSetProperty (kAUMIDISynthProperty_EnablePreload: 1) to AVAudioUnitMIDISynth

(2) << How to preload? >>

(3) AudioUnitSetProperty (kAUMIDISynthProperty_EnablePreload: 0) to AVAudioUnitMIDISynth

(4) Start AVAudioSequencer

Answer (score 0):

MIDI Player uses the `kAUMIDISynthProperty_EnablePreload` property of MIDISynth for that purpose. See the Apple comment about it below. Note the **It should only be used prior to MIDI playback and must be set back to 0 before attempting to start playback** sentence at the end :

```
/*!
    @constant       kAUMIDISynthProperty_EnablePreload
    @discussion         Scope:          Global
                        Value Type:     UInt32
                        Access:         Write
 
                    Setting this property to 1 puts the MIDISynth in a mode where it will attempt to load
                    instruments from the bank or file when it receives a program change message.  This
                    is used internally by the MusicSequence.  It should only be used prior to MIDI playback,
                    and must be set back to 0 before attempting to start playback.
 */
```

EDIT : frankly, I'm a little bit reserved about your link

```
One strategy I haven’t tried would be to pitch shift the MIDI up one octave, play it back at 2x, record it at 88.2kHz, then downsample to 44.1kHz. AVAudioSession presumably can’t go past 48kHz though.
```

Clearly, the person who wrote that has a very poor knowledge about audio and sampling. Playing a MIDI song transposed one octave up at double tempo is really not equivalent than playing the same recorded in audio at double speed whatever you make the recording at 88.2kHz or any other sample rate. As a simple example, what happens is the file contains a drum set ? A snare drum (40) will become a Chinese cymbal (52) played two times slower ?

As I can understand this post, the described hack has for unique purpose to make recording. So if you simply want to play your MIDI file back you can certainly find a simpler and better example.

Comment: dspr, Thank you for your advice.


How can I specifically load the SMF into the AVAudioUnitMIDISynth in the sample code in the link above?


(1) AudioUnitSetProperty (kAUMIDISynthProperty_EnablePreload: 1) to AVAudioUnitMIDISynth

(2) << How to preload? >>

(3) AudioUnitSetProperty (kAUMIDISynthProperty_EnablePreload: 0) to AVAudioUnitMIDISynth

(4) Start AVAudioSequencer